# Showing "Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1". Was running Flutter in Android Studio.What should I do?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, android-emulator

This was shown in the console

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: image not found
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
Launching lib/main.dart on vivo 1951 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in /Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
  >    build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  >    platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  >   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run flutter doctor --android-licenses in console and accept android licenses
then run flutter doctor to ensure everything is ok

Comment: Even after running flutter doctor and accepting the android license, it didn't work for me. But when I run flutter upgrade the error was removes

Thanks a Lot :))